# Close review audits which should be left open show a close notice box

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

Some review audits in `/review/close` for which the "correct" answer is Leave Open are showing an obviously fake close notice.

If it is proposed to vote to close a question, it should not be shown as already closed.

In this example, [originally reported at meta.SF](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5598/126632), the [question](https://serverfault.com/q/516164/126632) was actually open, but [showed up](https://serverfault.com/review/close/79212) in the close review queue with a close notice stating "put on hold as unclear what you're asking" dated five days ago, before the new close reasons came into being (they only went live yesterday on SF).

[image: review audit]

I've also personally seen a review audit with this bug (and [failed it, of course](https://serverfault.com/review/close/79067)).

The fake close notice is gone after the review is completed.

Comment: so you're saying the other bug is not actually a bug, but rather a feature (and so is this) to indicate it's an audit?

Comment: I don't think audits are supposed to be so blatantly obvious. I can't speculate on what the bug actually is (I'm ops, not dev!) but I'm pretty sure there is one in here.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Based on my original report of this, as you can see from my screenshot above, the problem is that the question appears to already be closed which immediately raises flags since it shouldn't be in the queue at all. It's also unfortunate in that it's a terrible question that deserves to be closed.

Comment: Yesterday, I saw this particular question audit _three times_.